# Python - Dictionary to NodeTree

Tags: python, python-2.7

I ask you for advice
I have a class NodeTree.
and then I have a function create_T (d)
This function takes as input a dictionary d that represents a tree, and creates a tree with nodes of type NodeTree
What do you advise me to do?
Thanks to all

Comment: Can you provide more details about the structure of the tree dictionary? What exactly was the difficulty you faced?

Comment: The dictionary function that takes as input ga two keys:
'name' = name of the node
'children' = value with the list of child nodes (which are themselves dictionaries of the same type)
The dictionary is a tree.
The difficulty is to implement the feature, which took as input the dictionary d, creates a tree with nodes of type NodeTree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your info is quite scant, so I've made some assumptions. Basically I think you need to know where to start in the tree. If you pick a random point then you have to work upwards and downwards. If you can work out which is the top of the tree then you just need to work downwards. I calculated the top of the tree by doing a set comparison to see which node was not a child of any other nodes.

```
import itertools

# NodeTree
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, child_node):
        self.children.append(child_node)

    def __repr__(self):
        if not self.children:
            return '<%s/>' % self.name
        else:
            children = ''.join([repr(child) for child in self.children])
            return '<%s>%s</%s>' % (self.name, children, self.name)

# create_T(d)
def create_tree(tree_dict):
    # find which node is the top of the tree (assume it is well-formed)
    all_leaves = set(itertools.chain(*tree_dict.values()))
    top_of_the_tree = set(tree_dict.keys()) - all_leaves

    def get_node(name):
        node = Node(name)
        for child_name in tree_dict[name]:
            node.add_child(get_node(child_name))
        return node
    return get_node(top_of_the_tree.pop())

print create_tree({'a': ['b', 'c'],
                   'b': ['d'],
                   'c': ['e'],
                   'd': [],
                   'e': [],
                   'f': ['a']})
```

giving:

> ```
>    <f><a><b><d/></b><c><e/></c></a></f>
> ```

Comment: generated by : all_leaves = set(itertools.chain(*tree_dict.values()))

Comment: You have not told us anything about what you have already tried to solve this problem. You have no track record on StackOverflow. I have picked apart your question, made lots of assumptions and solved your problem, providing you with full runnable source. Rather than provide any positive feedback you have said there is an error when you try your data, but you have not supplied any details of what your data is. You need to work harder from your end of the bargain. Consider this constructive feedback.